# print child rows along with parent table in datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I have a condition where there are a number of rows in a datatable. Each row has a number of child rows depicting the details of the entry. They are to be toggled(expanded/collapsed) on a click event.

The child rows are to be fetched dynamically upon click(their number can vary from 0 to n) and are not available prior.

I stumbled upon this code below to add child rows to each row.

```
$('#example tbody').on('click', 'td', function () {
            var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            var row = table.row( tr );

            if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
                // This row is already open - close it
                row.child.hide();
                tr.removeClass('shown');
            }
            else {
                // Open this row
                row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
                tr.addClass('shown');
            }
        } );

  function format ( d ) {

            return '<tr role="row">\n' +
                '                                        <td class="grey-column"><strong>Suspence account</strong></td>\n' +
                '                                        <td class="green-column">d</td>\n' +
                '                                        <td class="green-column">d</td>\n' +
                '                                        <td class="blue-column">d</td>\n' +
                '                                        <td class="blue-column">d</td>\n' +
                '                                        <td class="orange-column">d</td>\n' +
                '                                        <td class="orange-column">d</td>\n' +
                '                                    </tr>';
        }
```

This works perfectly for adding child rows, but I cannot seem to print them along with the parent table.

Also, I have this code to add rows underneath a row

```
$('#example tbody').on('click', 'td', function () {
        count=0;
        var currentPage = table.page();

    //insert a test row
    count++;
    table.row.add(['Account Name', 'green debit', 'green credit', 'blue debit', 'blue credit','orange debit', 'orange credit']).draw();

    //move added row to desired index (here the row we clicked on)
    var index = table.row(this).index(),
        rowCount = table.data().length-1,
        insertedRow = table.row(rowCount).data(),
        tempRow;

    for (var i=rowCount;i>index+1;i--) {
        tempRow = table.row(i-1).data();
        table.row(i).data(tempRow);
        table.row(i-1).data(insertedRow);
    }
    //refresh the current page
    table.page(currentPage).draw(false);

} );
```

The problem with this is that there is no distinction between the child and parent row. So, toggle(expand/collapse) seems to be out of question.

Can I somehow add child rows to a row dynamically upon click (with expand/collapse) and print it as a part of the main table?

Comment: Hi , can you create working demo code ?

Comment: Create something like this with your own code and it will be much easier to help you.  https://jsfiddle.net/gyrocode/2u650u18/